# Undefined reference of math functions during compiling ffmpeg on linux

Tags: linux, math, ffmpeg, makefile

i try to compile a version of ffmpeg source (ffmpeg2dwave) in a Linux system via a `make` command that is provided.
Make runs fine except at some point i get errors like below:

```
libavcodec/eval.c:252: undefined reference to `cosh'
 undefined reference to `tanh'
 undefined reference to `sin'
 undefined reference to `cos'
```

etc (more functions follow)

do i have to check someting about the `math.h` function? any ideas?

many thanks

Comment: is it compiling with `-lm` option?

Comment: i use a make file which has this entry LDFLAGS+= -g after the CFLAGS
should i add/replace something there?
please note also that when i compiled in cygwin environment not problem existed!

Comment: i tried to use -lm or -lmath as CFLAGS or LDFLAGS but no good.
Is there a known issue when you include math.h in linux?

Comment: Does make pass the flags before the source/object file, perhaps? The libraries would need to be passed after, so the linker knows what symbols it needs to link.

Comment: that is the compile line : gcc -L"/home/geogeo/ffmpeg-2dwave"/libavformat -L"/home/geogeo/ffmpeg-2dwave"/libavcodec -L"/home/geogeo/ffmpeg-2dwave"/libavutil -lm -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath-link,"/home/geogeo/ffmpeg-2dwave"/libavcodec -Wl,-rpath-link,"/home/geogeo/ffmpeg-2dwave"/libavformat -Wl,-rpath-link,"/home/geogeo/ffmpeg-2dwave"/libavutil -g -o ffmpeg_g-2dwave ffmpeg.o cmdutils.o -lavformat-2dwave -lavcodec-2dwave -lavutil-2dwave -lpthread -lrt  -lz

Comment: @user2609910: You must list libraries (which the `-lm` switch does; it stands for the `libm` library) **after** other linker input files that depend on them, because the linker only extracts a module from a library if it already knows there is something that needs that module

Comment: solved! the -lm had to be placed in the correct spot. Thanks!